Как программно включить Water Lock на Wear OS?
У меня стоит задача по программному включение режима Water Lock на Wear Os, насколько я понял официально Google и Android такую возможность не предоставляют. Есть ли хоть какие-то способы? Или в крайнем случае как перекинуть юзера на экран включения Water Lock, я пробовал писать подобный Intent, но не нашел необходимый Action.
